# Allow multiple instances of Handbrake

Tags: video, conversion, video-editing, video-conversion, handbrake

Is it possible to run multiple instances of Handbrake on Windows 7 (video encoding application)?

I have a 32 thread system and I think it would be more efficient to encode 2-3 movies at the same time. (Handbrake does not use all 16 cores at the moment)

Comment: Have you tried to just run the application more then once?

Comment: Yes, error with writing to the log file. Then handbrake crashes.

Comment: Doesn't handbrake just act as a GUI wrapper for x264? if so, why not just download x264 and run multiple instances of that? bound to be more efficient anyway

Comment: I would, but it seems easier to create queues in handbrake GUI. Unless you know of a simple command to queue an entire folder?

Comment: Haven't got time to write something now, but you could probably do this with powershell. This looks like a pretty good start after a quick google: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2011/04/04/scaling-and-queuing-powershell-background-jobs.aspx Just need to change to launch an external executable  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx